# Display and Close image through bash script Rpi

Tags: pi-zero-w, bash

I am trying to display image and close it through bash/shell script on a raspberry pi. My program opens the image but it doesn't close.
what am I doing wrong?
 Can it be done in the same script 
I am using feh to display image.
Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(feh -F image1.jpg)
PID=`ps -eaf | grep feh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]; then
  echo "killing $PID"
  kill -9 $PID
fi
```

Comment: What's the output of the echo? Do you get any output at all, or does the entire if block not run?

Comment: it outputs kill usage syntax when I manually close the image (exit the process). If I have any other images already displayed before running this script it closes all the other images and outputs the pid's when I manually close the current script image(image1.jpg)

Comment: it doesn't output anything only after I manually close the image it outputs (kill syntax ) like   "kill:usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... .....  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not getting the PID until the process has finished (and it's not particularly clear that your attempt to get the PID is working at all; it looks like it isn't!). I'm guessing your pipe simply blocks until the image viewer exits, at which point it's too late to kill it, even if the command did get the right PID.

You can just get the PID of the process of `feh` that you launched with `$!`, e.g.

```
feh -F image1.jpg &
PID = "$!"
kill -9 $PID
```

Note that the `&` was necessary in this example so that `feh` didn't block and launched in the background, so our script could carry on running.

You can adapt this to suit your needs if there are any special constraints you have.

Comment: when I add  &  the output is the same, the process doesn't stop until I manually close the current image. when I close the image shows the kill syntax as the pid doesn't exist anymore. But when I add  " \& " it says " feh WARNING & doesn't exist - skipping".

Comment: Is there any other way to make sure the script is running without the process blocking it?

Comment: I did this with two scripts. I opened the image in script 1 and I called the script 1 in script 2 with & and kill in script 2.  Then it worked.  But is there a way to do it in the same script.

Comment: @Sneha That's odd. The code in my example definitely works; I just tried it locally. Perhaps [edit] in the exact code you're using now into your question, so I can take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @ Aurora0001 Thanks! It worked. My mistake, I wrote the command in echo.